# What should this 'unexpected' refer to?

Tags: exam-questions

> Harding was unable to _____the results of the survey; although entirely *unexpected*, **the figures** were obtained by **a market research firm** with an impeccable reputation.

It is from the SAT exam. When I first read it I thought that *unexpected* refers to the research firm with an impeccable reputation: it was unexpected that the firm would turn out to have impeccable reputation.

But the book says that unexpected refers to the figures, the figures were unexpected.

Am I a tad right?

Comment: I agree with the book. It was Harding who found the figures unexpected.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Even without Harding being mentioned, I would expect _unexpected_ to refer to the subject of the following clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It definitely refers to the **figures**, as that is the *subject* of the clause that follows "although entirely unexpected".

It can semantically *not* refer to the firm, as that would mean the firm was unexpected, which seems to make less than a little sense.

If you want to convey that the firms good reputation was unexpected, it would be much clearer if the sentence would have been differently formulated, for instance:

> notwithstanding the figures being incredible, they were obtained by a market research firm with an unexpected impeccable reputation.

You could use unexpectedly as well. *Unexpected* modifies *reputation*, *unexpectedly* modifies *impeccable*.

Reading the sentence again and again, and trying to formulate a simpler one, I agree it could refer to the *reputation*, although I fail to see what mechanism causes that.

> Although entirely unexpected, the creatures came from a red planet.

In this case there seems to be an obvious implication that we might have expected creatures from a blue planet, but not from a red one.

In that interpretation, though, it is the fact that the figures *came* from such a firm that is unexpected - not the fact that this particular firm has such a reputation.

So instead of saying:

> It was unexpected that the firm would turn out to have impeccable reputation.

I would say

> It was unexpected that such a reputed firm would produce these figures.

Comment: Unexpected could definitely refer to the reputation of the firm (impeccable) being counter-expectant.

Comment: I don't understand how or why, but I agree :) See my edit / addition :)

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit of a strange reading, admittedly - it's probably happening at the adjective level - "entirely unexpected" is modifying "impeccable reputation". Since the commas flag a constituent movement of some kind here, I'd say that you could rephrase as "The figures were obtained by a market research firm with an _entirely unexpected_ impeccable reputation."

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's three readings of this.
Harding was unable to believe the results of the survey; although entirely unexpected, the figures were obtained by a market research firm with an impeccable reputation:

- ...and Harding thought it must have been an *incompetent* market research firm.
- ...and Harding was expecting *different* results (or figures).
- ...and Harding was not expecting them to produce any results at all.

The last one is a bit unusual, and I would say that the second one is the *unmarked* reading of it.